# Site Accessibility Issue: IP address works, domain name does not in desktop browser; reversed in mobile browser

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, https, bitnami

I volunteer to help out with a website for a local organization. The person who set it up is unavailable to help me so I'm coming to you.

The situation: The website (www.castrocountryclub.org) shows a privacy (certificate) error when I try to access it via Chrome or Edge desktop browsers. However, when go to the IP address it works fine. It's reversed in mobile Chrome: URL is fine but IP address throws the error.

This is a Bitnami WordPress site hosted on AWS with a certificate purchased from GoDaddy.

I've been struggling with this for days. Every set of instructions I find seems to be a network of rabbit holes. If anyone has experience with these technologies and is will to help me out I'd be much obliged.

Answer (score 0):

In my Chrome: `https://castrocountryclub.org` works fine, but there's a problem with `https://www.castrocountryclub.org` and that is because the DNS isn't configured for that.

You have to add a `CNAME` entry for `www` pointing to you domain's IP address and it can be done like so:

```
type    name    value    TTL
CNAME   www     @        1 hour
```

Please check the [GoDaddy's help](https://www.godaddy.com/help/add-a-cname-record-19236) for that case - there's all explained in detail.

Comment: Thank you for the concise and thorough reply. I've made the changes you recommend and now I'm waiting "up to 48 hours for all changes to take full effect" as mentioned on the help page to which you provided a link. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, and DNS settings are fine now, but there's a new potential problem - Firefox and Edge says that the certificate has been revoked. If you see the same please check another godaddy's help pages: https://www.godaddy.com/help/rekey-my-certificate-4976 and https://www.godaddy.com/help/revoke-a-certificate-4747